# How to pull elements of JSON files in a for loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, for-loop, discord.js

I'm working on building an extension system for one of my projects in discord.js, and I need to pull content from JSON files that the user places in the `./modules` directory. These files can have any name, and are supposed to be structured like this:

`./modules/module_name.json`:

```
{
    "name": "(module name)",
    "author": "(author name)",
    "commands": {
        "command1": "(url_of_command)/command1.js",
        "command2": "(url_of_command)/command2.js",
        etc...etc...
    }
}
```

My current code looks like this:

`./index.js`:

```
/*

Toggle - Command indexer

Original code by Anden Wieseler and ZedTek. For Licensing info, see https://github.com/ZedTek-Official/toggle-base/blob/main/LICENSE

*/

// Tell console that we're ready

console.log('Toggle v1 - STARTED');

// Load dependencies and get global vars

const http = require('http');
const fs = require("fs")
const db = require("quick.db")
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const global = require('./globalTMP.json');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const prefix = global.info.prefix;

// Kickoff

client.on("ready", () =>{
    client.user.setPresence({
        game: {
            name: global.info.game.name,
            type: global.info.game.type
        }
    });
    loadExt();
});

function loadExt(){
    const moduleFiles = fs.readdirSync(`./modules`).filter(file => file.endsWith('.json'));
    for (const module of moduleFiles){
        const mod = require(`./modules/${module}`)
        if (db.get('parsedModules') === module){
            return;
        }
        else{
            for (const command of mod.commands){
                download(command, `./commands/ext/${module.name}/${command}`, error);
            }
            db.add('parsedModules', module)
        }
        
        
    }
}

// Discord API login

client.login(global.token);
```

^^ I've omitted code that is irrelevant to this question.

When I run the code, I get an error saying that `mod.commands isn't iterable`. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You sure mod.commands is what you think it is? Have you verified you are getting back what you expect? The error seems pretty clear, you are trying to iterate over something that is not iterable. Log the value of mod.commands and verify you are iterating over what you think .

Comment: @basic, it prints out the array of `commands` as expected

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you cannot run `for (const command of mod.commands)` on an object, you have to use `for (let command in mod.commands)`. `command` in this case will be the key, so instead of what is currently `command` in your code, you'd need to do `mod.commands[command]`.

Example:

```
for (let command in mod.commands){
                download(mod.commands[command], `./commands/ext/${module.name}/${mod.commands[command]}`, error);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because commands is not an array is an object and each command an attribute on that object.

You can do something like this instead:

```js
const data = {
    "name": "(module name)",
    "author": "(author name)",
    "commands": {
        "command1": "(url_of_command)/command1.js",
        "command2": "(url_of_command)/command2.js",
    }
}

const commands = Object.keys(data.commands);
for (let commandAtt of commands) {
  const cmd = data.commands[commandAtt];
    console.log(cmd);
}
```

Or

```js
const data = {
    "name": "(module name)",
    "author": "(author name)",
    "commands": {
        "command1": "(url_of_command)/command1.js",
        "command2": "(url_of_command)/command2.js",
    }
}

for (let commandAtt in data.commands) {
  const cmd = data.commands[commandAtt];
  console.log(cmd);
}
```